# How do I update my patch to tomcat web application?

Tags: database, tomcat, web-applications

My team handles one web application (running in tomcat) in live mode. It’s 2 years old application. Now we add some new columns in existing database tables. So we need to update our existing database without dropping the database.  Is there is any way to, alter my database tables without drop my database.

FYI: This web application developed by using spring3.0, hibernate ,Mysql

Comment: Yes. `alter table` is there for that. Check the documentation of your database for the exact syntax.